# how do I get my bot to say who deleted the message?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I was following various guides, and I built this `message create` event but was having a problem getting it to say who sent the message.

Here is my code

```
badword = ['test']

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.content == badword){
        message.delete(message)
        .then(msg => console.log(`Deleted message from ${msg.author.username.tag}`))
        .catch(console.error);
    }
})
```

And the console log

```
Deleted message from undefined
```

I was also wondering if I could make it get rid of any message that includes the word instead of the message being  strictly 'test'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to access the tag is just `message.author.tag`, because `user.username` is just a string and not an object. [Here's the `User` object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/User) from the discord.js docs.

So your console.log statement should just be:

```js
console.log(`Deleted message from ${msg.author.tag}`)
```

Comment: Glad you got it working. Consider accepting this answer as the solution so that future users can see immediately that this answer works. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) about accepting answers. And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: So sorry I did not know how but I have done it now.